# EJB 1.1 stubs generation in RAD9

Tags: java, ejb, rad, stubs

Am working on legacy code which EJB v1.1. Due to RAD version issues we could not migrate complete code to compatibility level of RAD 9. So am trying generate stubs for EJB 1.1 using ejbdeploy manually so i can still use these projects in RAD 9.

When i execute ejbdeploy i get below error -

```
[*Error] ... (Class: ...)CHKJ2408E: <clinit>() must be public. (EJB 1.1: 6.10.4).
CHKJ2410E: ... (Class: ...)<clinit>() must not be static. (EJB 1.1: 6.10.4).
```

Anyone has any idea here?

Comment: It's some sort of version mismatch.

Comment: am not understanding how? as ejbdeploy does generates stubs for EJB 1.x and 2.x as per EJB/RAD specs.